# Excel VBA IF greater than or less than not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to test if the old value of a cell is greater or less than the current value being inserted. However, it keeps saying it's neither.

I really have no idea why... Can anyone help me out?

```
Dim oldCellValue As Integer
Dim curSheetName As String
Dim curCellAddress As String
Dim curCellValue As Integer

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldCellValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    curSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    curCellAddress = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address
    curCellValue = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

    If oldCellValue = 0 And curCellValue = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open("stock.xlsx")

        If oldCellValue > curCellValue Then
            Sheets(curSheetName).Range(curCellAddress) = ActiveCell.Value + (oldCellValue - curCellValue)
        ElseIf curCellValue < oldCellValue Then
            Sheets(curSheetName).Range(curCellAddress) = ActiveCell.Value - (curCellValue - oldCellValue)
        Else
            MsgBox "Neither"
        End If

        Workbook.Save
        Workbook.Close

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I've updated the code with the suggestions and the fix, even though there's a new problem. See below comments.

```
Dim oldCellValue As Integer
Dim curSheetName As String
Dim curCellAddress As String
Dim curCellValue As Integer

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldCellValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    curSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    curCellAddress = Target.Address
    curCellValue = Target.Value

    If oldCellValue = 0 And curCellValue = 0 Or oldCellValue = curCellValue Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open("stock.xlsx")

        If oldCellValue > curCellValue Then
            Sheets(curSheetName).Range(curCellAddress) = ActiveCell.Value + (oldCellValue - curCellValue)
            MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
        Else
            Sheets(curSheetName).Range(curCellAddress) = ActiveCell.Value - (curCellValue - oldCellValue)
            MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
        End If

        Workbook.Save
        Workbook.Close

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  Are two cells right above and below each other indeed equal?  In `Change`, try using `Target` instead of `ActiveCell` and see if that helps.

Comment: In your `Change` event handler, you're setting the `curCellValue = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value` which seems like it might be wrong logic. Why isn't `curCellValue = Target.Value`  ???

Comment: Also what are the values of `oldCellValue` and `curCellValue` at the time the `If/ElseIf` is evaluated? If you don't know, please use debugging techniques with Print/MsgBox, or breakpoints to examine the data in Locals window.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the `Set Workbook =` line. Run the code. What's the value of `oldCellValue` and `curCellValue` when the debugger stops and highlights the line with the breakpoint? You can find out by typing `?oldCellValue, curCellValue` in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Looks like you have a typo or overlooked your logic in the If/Else see @cyboashu's response :)

Comment: Thank you all, specially @DavidZemens for the tip on Target.Value. I've got another problem though, see comment in cyboashu answer if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oldCellValue > curCellValue` and `curCellValue < oldCellValue` are technically the same conditions.

if oldcell value= 10 and New cell value =11

then `oldCellValue > curCellValue` =False  `(10 >11)`

and so is

`curCellValue < oldCellValue`  = False  `(11 < 10)`

Change `curCellValue < oldCellValue` to `curCellValue > oldCellValue`

Comment: This pretty much solved my problem! Thanks a lot, what a silly me :) If it isn't too much to ask, can you check my edit? It's now working, however the `ActiveCell.Value` in the count is giving me a blank value. Basically I want to retrieve the value from the target file...

Comment: Nevermind, tried `Sheets(curSheetName).Range(curCellAddress).Value` and it worked, obviously. Thanks again.